# How do I conditionally enable a managed repo using puppet-yum?

Tags: puppet, hiera

The [puppet-yum](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-yum/blob/master/README.md) documentation is very straightforward, and explains how to add your own managed repo via hiera data. However, in addition to our 'release' repo, I want to conditionally add our 'build' repo to servers in our 'test' environment.

In a puppet class (init, probably), how can I (conditionally) toggle 'enable' on a nested value in common.yaml?

```
yum::managed_repos:
    - 'project_build'
yum::repos:
    project_build:
        descr: 'project build repo'
        ensure: 'absent' <----this needs to be 'present' in the test env
        enabled: true
        baseurl: 'https://repo.example.corp/project/el/$releasever/build/$basearch/'
        gpgcheck: false
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the documentation, you should go ahead and define the repo with ensure set to present. But, omit it from the `yum::managed_repos` key in `common.yaml`.

> **On its own, the repos parameter does nothing.** The resource names from the hash must be selected via the `managed_repos` parameter.

Then, you would create a new hierarchy in Hiera based on the `$::environment` Fact. Under that directory a `test.yaml` file would have the expected:

```
yum::managed_repos:
    - 'project_build'
```

Look in the example here where they have a Hiera level for `$::trusted.certname`. You can use that as a pattern for what you want to do with `$::environment`.

https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-yum/blob/master/README.md#enable-managemnt-of-multiple-repos